# Quitar o ocultar valores nulos de una consulta

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Hola tengo el siguiente código que me funciona bien, pero necesito quitar o que al escoger los 5 primeros registros no tenga en cuenta los valores nulos es decir que no me aparezca salespersonid=None, alguien me podria ayudar

```
SELECT salespersonid, COALESCE(SUM(subtotal),0) AS subtotal_vendedor 
FROM salesorderheader WHERE orderdate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
GROUP BY salespersonid ORDER BY subtotal_vendedor DESC LIMIT 5;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No intentaste colocando en el `WHERE salespersonid != '' and orderdate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31' ...`

Comment: No funciono, estoy desde python me genera lo siguiente: DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input syntax for integer: ""
LINE 10: WHERE (b.salespersonid != '' AND b.orderdate BETWEEN '2014-0...  
                                                                                                                               y trato con doble corechete y me genera lo siguiente lumn " " does not exist
LINE 10: WHERE (b.salespersonid != " " AND b.orderdate BETWEEN '2014-...

Comment: ah oks porque es tipo integer, intenta `b.salespersonid != null`

Answer (score 2):

Si necesitas filtrar los nulos debes usar el operador `is null` o `is not null` en tu caso pudiera ser:

```
SELECT salespersonid, COALESCE(SUM(subtotal),0) AS subtotal_vendedor 
FROM salesorderheader WHERE orderdate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
and salespersonid is not null
GROUP BY salespersonid ORDER BY subtotal_vendedor DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Yo le agregaría el filtro `and salespersonid <> 'None'` para irme a la segura. +1